# Is there a way to use python and java in the same program?

Tags: java, python

I want to use both python and java in the same program. Since the `print()` function of python is better, but java's `int variable;` is more efficient.

Comment: Not sure what the tag `tabstop` has to do  with your question. Maybe you can edit it and add tags like Java and Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting correctly, you want to use to use both interchangeably in the same file, so you'd end up with code like:

```
def main():
    int x = 5;
    print(x)
```

This is impossible, because there would be ambiguity when trying to interpret code if you allowed constructs from both languages. For example, `"X" + 1` is allowed in java, and would give you the string "X1". In python, it would give you an error because you can't add an int to a string. This would mean that there would be no way to know what your code should do because it's runnable in both languages.

This is a problem that all of us face, where we like some parts of some languages and other parts of other languages. The solution is pretty much just to decide what's most important, choose one language based on that, and then put up with the parts you don't like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jython](https://www.jython.org), which is a Python implementation based on the JVM/JDK. This allows calling between Java and Python code in both directions.